# .NET Blazor Web Template Get Stuck in Loading with Kestrel

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor, kestrel-http-server

When the content of pages increases, for example, I add an HTML template to Layout, both in the IIS express web server and in Kestrel, it gives the following error:

`InvalidOperationException: Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call WriteAsync or set AllowSynchronousIO to true instead.`

When I change the Program class with these codes, the above error is resolved and the problem is resolved in the IIS Express web server, but in the Kestrel web server, only a part of the page is loaded and the rest is not displayed.

```
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => {options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; }); 
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options => {options.AllowSynchronousIO = true; });
```

Because I want it to run on Linux, I have to use the Kestrel web server.
Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

**Expected Behavior:**
Show Page without problem in Kestrel

**Steps To Reproduce:**
make a page with this code

```
@page "/test"
@layout EmptyLayout
<PageTitle>Test Page</PageTitle>
<h1>Test</h1>
<p>This is test.</p>

@if (_isLoading)
{
    <p>
        <em>Loading...</em>
    </p>
}
else
{
    @foreach (var item in _messageList)
    {
        @item
    }
}

@code {
    private readonly List<string> _messageList = new();
    private bool _isLoading = true;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
        {
            _messageList.Add($"This is Test : {i}  ");
        }
        _isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

**Exceptions (if any):**
IIS Express Work Fine

**.NET Version:**
8.0.0-preview.7.23375.9

**Screenshot**
[image: page not load completely and get stuck in loading]

Comment: You can try the other version like .Net7 or  8.0.0-preview. 3.23178  .   The .Net 8 preview has some  problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a lot and found a workaround for this problem.

Based on the "[StaticHtmlRenderer uses synchronous writes which eventually fails](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/49172)" Issue in GitHub, this problem was fixed by the [#49860 pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/49860) and added to the .NET 8 RC1 release.

nightly build containing this fix right now.

I installed .NET 8.0.100-rc.1.23416.14 from [Here](https://github.com/dotnet/installer/blob/main/README.md#installers-and-binaries) in the main column of table in the page then the problem is solved.

To RC release NuGet, I have to add a new repository to the NuGet config with this link in Visual Studio.

```
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet8/nuget/v3/index.json
```

Also, because it's an RC release, some Debugger Signature Validation Errors need to be disabled, and in my case, Visual Studio 2022 preview needs to be run from the command line.

To start from the command line, I added my Visual Studio 2022 preview installation folder to the user environment variable by editing the "Path" key and adding a new value to it.

```
    D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\Common7\IDE\
```

After that, I created a new "runvs.bat" file on my desktop, added the command below to it, and executed the file.

```
start devenv
```

Microsoft published the instruction to [Resolving Signature Validation Errors In Visual Studio Here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/workflow/debugging/coreclr/debugging-runtime.md#resolving-signature-validation-errors-in-visual-studio).